bitbucket push not working even though pull is working fine (SSH)
hopefully someone can help here
Im having issues using git push (git pull works fine) - i have a SSH key set up, but still get the following error :
Unauthorized
fatal: Could not read from remote repository
Please make sure you have the correct access rights and the repository exists
I have used git + bitbucket for quite some time, but have recently got a new laptop (macbook air m3) so may have done a step wrong during setup (previous computer worked fine with pull and push)
any help would be greatly appreciated

You could git config --list and check if the config looks correct.

Does the remote use SSH (git remote -v should list the full URL)?
